# How to set up a continuously running processes along with Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am setting up backend for an application, with Django and MySQL.

As a part of the set up, I need to keep on fetching latest content from Facebook and Twitter Graph APIs and keep updating my database with that.

The user of my application would pull this latest available data from the database.

Now,how and where I implant this code? Shall I put it somewhere in the Django project, if yes, then where?

Or shall I use it as an independent script i.e. not attached to Django in anyway, and update the DB directly with that.

Also since this would be a continuous process, I need it to run as background task. It should not eat consume any resources that might be needed by the foreground tasks.

Comment: For Background task, try out http://www.celeryproject.org/..

Comment: You can definitely write a script and use linux's crontab to execute the script at a predefined interval. I have also read celery can do it like @Pawan suggested.

Comment: I realize it can be done independently. But isn't there any recommended way. Won't doing it under Django shall be correct way of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is using [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). If you want don't want to use async task handling you can also just create a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/) and run it via cron. Both of them should work with the whole projects  context (e.g. what your defined in your settings), so you can use the Django ORM to connect to your DB etc..